# Azure DevOps if else condition for terraform plan

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I am using Azure DevOps for provisioning my cloud resources. I have created a pipeline and its successfully provisions cloud resources. But now there is a new request that when there is a destructive change in the terraform plan then the pipeline should wait for manual approval. From the below link, I found that
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform&ssr=false#overview
the "Terraform plan destroy detection for destroy" variable can be used for my use case. But can somebody help me with how can I write the code 'if there is a destructive change then manual verification has to trigger else the step should be skipped?

Below is my code snippet.

```
 # Run show to detect destroy operations
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
  displayName: 'terraform show'
  inputs:
    command: show
    inputTargetPlanOrStateFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/tfplan'

- stage: manual_validation
  displayName: "Manual Validation Phase"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.RequireManualValidation }}', true), eq(stageDependencies.terraform_plan.outputs['terraform_plan_job.produceVar.TERRAFORM_PLAN_HAS_CHANGES'], 'true'))
  pool: server
  jobs:
  - job: 'manual_validation'
    displayName: 'Please approve in order to proceed'
    timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.ApprovalTimeoutMinutes }}
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: '${{ parameters.PlanApprovers }}'
        instructions: 'look on the plan stage and approve the planned changes'
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

Comment: If you're still struck with the issue, you may refer to this link, I took this as an example and modified to my need. https://www.mediaglasses.blog/2021/06/08/azure-devops-terraform-pipeline-with-checkov-approvals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not posting my entire code here, hope you can do the rest.
After saving your plan file, it can be read to find these changes.
In my case I am going for

1. auto approve when there is only 'create'
2. if 'change or destroy' is found then go for manual validation.
3. No change means exit

```yaml
          - task: Bash@3
            name: "showPlan"
            displayName: "Display > Plan"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(FILE_PATH)"
              failOnStderr: true
              script: |
                terraform show plan.out
          
          - task: Bash@3
            name: "setvar"
            displayName: "Vars > Set Variables for next stage"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(FILE_PATH)"
              failOnStderr: true
              script: |
                # If no changes, no-op and don't continue
                if terraform show plan.out | grep -q "No changes"; then 
                  echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]ℹ️ - No changes detected, terraform apply will not run"
                  # Check if resources destroyed. If no, don't require approval
                elif terraform show plan.out | grep -q "0 to change, 0 to destroy"; then
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HAS_CHANGES_ONLY;isOutput=true]true"
                  echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning] - Changes with no destroys detected, it is safe for the pipeline to proceed automatically"
                # Check if resources destroyed. If yes, require approvals
                else 
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HAS_DESTROY_CHANGES;isOutput=true]true"
                  echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]⛔️ - Changes or Destroy detected, pipeline will require a manual approval to proceed"
                fi
```

After setting these variables, in next stage(**Auto-approve/create**): in 'condition' checking from previous stage->Jobs

```yaml
- stage: "tfAutoApprove"
    displayName: "Terraform > Auto approve"
   
    condition: |
      and
        (
          succeeded(),
          eq(dependencies.terraformPlan.outputs['TerraformJobs.setvar.HAS_CHANGES_ONLY'], 'true'),
          ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

**For Manual Validation**

```yaml
- stage: "tfManualApprove"
    displayName: "Terraform Manual Approve"
    
    condition: |
      and
        (
          succeeded(),
          eq(dependencies.terraformPlan.outputs['TerraformJobs.setvar.HAS_DESTROY_CHANGES'], 'true'),
          ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
        )
```

In both the stages, you can have terraform init and apply once the condition is checked.

```
**Note:** In 'Condition' -> terraformPlan (stagename)
                          -> TerraformJobs (JobName under above stage)
                            -> setvar(taskname under above job)
```

Hope this helps!